Mostrar/Ocultar div dependiendo del dato tenga un input. asp.net
estoy iniciando con asp.net En un formulario tengo 2 div, al editar un registro se devuelve un dato en un input según el registro que se consulta, dependiendo del dato mostrado en el input debo mostrar ya sea el div1 o el div2.
Tengo un script que no funciona ya que aún estoy iniciando con desarrollo web.
Agradezco de antemano quien pueda ayudarme a solucionarlo.
Saludos.
En el formulario tengo lo siguiente:
//Aquí se muestra el resultado de la consulta:

<div class="row col-md-2">
    <label asp-for="tipoper" class="control-label">Tipo de Persona</label>
    <input asp-for="tipoper" class="form-control" readonly="true" name="opcion" id="opcion" onchange="mostrarDiv()" />
</div>

//Estos son los div a mostrar u ocultar:

<div id="div1" class="div-container">

</div>

<div id="div2" class="div-container">

</div>

// Este es el Script
function mostrarDiv() {
    var opcion1 = document.getElementById('div1');
    var opcion2 = document.getElementById('div2');
    var showId = document.getElementById('opcion').value;
    document.getElementById('opcion').value = showId;
    if (opcion == 'Fisica' {
        opcion1.style.display = 'block';
        opcion2.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        opcion1.style.display = 'none';
        opcion2.style.display = 'block';
    }
}


Si el input es readonly, que caso tiene hacer un script para mostrar/ocultar divs, si el usuario nunca podrá cambiar dicho valor??? Si ese fuese el caso, lo mejor hacerlo en asp

Es readonly porque el dato ya viene al editar el registro y el usuario no puede cambiarlo, solo se permite cambiar el resto de los campos.

Lo he solucionado así:
function mostrarDiv() {
    var opcion1 = document.getElementById('div1');
    var opcion2 = document.getElementById('div2');
    var showId = document.getElementById('opcion').value;

    if (showId === 'Fisica') {
        opcion1.style.display = 'block';
        opcion2.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        opcion1.style.display = 'none';
        opcion2.style.display = 'block';
    }
}

window.onload = function () {
    mostrarDiv();
}

Gracias
